# Cambridge University "overall grade"?

Tags: graduate-admissions, undergraduate, united-kingdom, grades, international-students

I'm from Brazil and the metric system for grades here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grading_systems_by_country#Brazil) is different from UK.
So, I'm an undergraduate student who wants to apply to a Master Degree in Physics - DAMTP.
But, I don't know what exactly is the "overall grades" which they are requiring here https://www.graduate.study.cam.ac.uk/international-qualifications
I mean, I must to have 9/10 in each of the subjects or just the "final grade of all the course subjects" (given by some sort of process like weighted average)?

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: Do you not get a final grade/ classification for your degree? That is what they are asking for (overall grade 9/10 is considered equivalent to a 1st class UK degree).

Comment: Following on from that, I doubt you need 9/10 in every subject (you can get a 1st overall here without getting a 1st in every module).

Comment: @astronat is this about the course offered by the university or the grades of an student?

Comment: The two are connected: every course has a grade requirement that needs to be met by the student. The grade on your degree certificate needs to be 9/10 or higher if the course requirement is a 1st. If for some reason you don't get given a final grade you need to contact Cambridge and ask if you are eligible.